Linear least squares with selective parameter fitting
Suppose I have a linear model depending on 2 sets of parameters $a,b$
$$
z(t) = \sum_i a_i \Phi_i(t) + \sum_j b_j \Psi_j(t)
$$
Now suppose my data vector $z$ can be naturally divided into 2 sets: $x,y$. My measurements $y$ are well suited to resolving both sets of parameters $a,b$. However my measurements $x$ are better suited for only resolving the parameters $b$ (due to higher noise characteristics, $x$ is not well suited for resolving the $a$ parameters).
So I want to avoid fitting the $x$ measurements to the $a$ parameters, because doing so could contaminate the $a$ results. Would it be correct to then construct my least squares matrix by setting all entries to 0 in the rows corresponding to $x$ data and columns corresponding to $a$ parameters? Or would this lead to strange results when solving the least squares system?

How would you determine the proper value of $a$ when fitting $b$ with the $x$ data? This seems like it might be better-suited to a statistical/Bayesian inverse problem framework since you have different noise characteristics for different parts of the data

What is $\Phi_i$? A linear or nonlinear function?

sorry I wrote it wrong - I have fixed the equation so that the model is linear in $a,b$

I don't think there is any validity in selectively not fitting one parameter to some data while fitting another parameter to all of the data. You can weight the least-squares formulation to accommodate the different noise levels and if the results are still poor you can regularize to ensure the resulting parameter values are sensible
